# Check what culture a date string is, then convert it to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, date, datetime

For my application a 3rd party application (running on Java) delivers strings that are dates. Now this application somehow uses the system language to give out the date string.

So April 6th 2009 may look like this:

- Apr 6, 2009 (en-US)
- 06-Apr-2009 (en-GB)
- 6 avr. 2009 (fr-FR)
- 06.04.2009 (de-DE)

and so on..

For my application I need to convert these strings to DateTime. I am aware of the methods `Convert.ToDateTime()`, `DateTime.Parse()` and `DateTime.ParseExact()`.

This code is how I could distinguish between en-US and de-DE:

```
private static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(string source)
{
        CultureInfo cuDe = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        CultureInfo cuEn = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        var result = new DateTime();

        if (source.Contains("."))
        {
            result = Convert.ToDateTime(source, cuDe);
        }
        else
        {
            result = Convert.ToDateTime(source, cuEn);
        }

        return result;
}
```

This would of course not work for a string in fr-FR. My problem is that I do not know which language will be set on the systems the 3rd party application is running.

So my question is: Is there any way to check which culture date format a string represents? So that I would for example input "6 avr. 2009" and it would return fr-FR? Or do I really have to check for every possible language date format that may turn up and check it myself for example by running `string.Contains()` for months in the specific language?

Notes:

- I cannot change the 3rd party application or its output
- I cannot get additional information about the system that application runs on

Comment: `foreach (CultureInfo cultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))`

Comment: How will you handle strings with multiple syntax valid interpretations? `06.04.2009` might be 6th of April as it might be the 4th of June if you have no other information?

Comment: It most likely not possible in general, because different cultures might have different interpretations of exactly the same date string. So real fix would be ask third party developer to fix their application to either provide culture or normal date strings.

Comment: Unless you have a finite list of possible formats, all distinguishable from one another, or any other way to indicate what the possible formats might be, it just can't be done. Nothing in `06/04/09` can indicate if it's 6th of April, 4th of June or even 9th of April 2006.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. This is what I was fearing.. So probably my only approach is to build a list of formats myself and distinguish between as many as I can manually..

Comment: 06-Apr-2009 does not look like any en-GB format I've ever encountered before.  Is this Java's weird idea of how we format dates in GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is not possible to find out which original culture was used to create the string just by looking at it.

Consider the following example:

```
var date = new DateTime(1900, 12, 11);

var enUs = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var enGb = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

var strUs = date.ToString(enUs);
var strGb = date.ToString(enGb);
```

Output for `strUs` will be `12/11/1900`.

Output for `strGb` will be `11/12/1900`. Note that month and day are inverted in US format.

By just looking at the string, we can not tell which is the month and which is the day. This is the reason why APIs should use an unambiguous format like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

---

That being said, if we known the exact formats used by the external service and these formats are distinguishable, you can try to parse with the known format strings.

```
private static DateTime ParseMultiCulture(string dateString) {
    DateTime output;

    string[] formatsEnUs = {"MMM d, yyyy"};
    string[] formatsEnGB = {"dd-MMM-yyyy"};
    string[] formatsFrFr = {"d MMM yyyy"};
    string[] formatsDeDe = {"dd.MM.yyyy"};


    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formatsEnUs, new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
            DateTimeStyles.None, out output)) {
        return output;
    }

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formatsEnGB, new CultureInfo("en-GB"), 
            DateTimeStyles.None, out output)) {
        return output;
    }

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formatsFrFr, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), 
            DateTimeStyles.None, out output)) {
        return output;
    }

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formatsDeDe, new CultureInfo("de-De"), 
            DateTimeStyles.None, out output)) {
        return output;
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException("Given datestring is in a format that is not supported.");
}
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DpAkvL)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While I am was aware of this I was kind of hoping there would be a clever way to still distinguish them. For the enUS and enGB strings I get as outputs it could be done by looking at the separators for example.. But that might not work for every format I guess

Comment: Based on the concrete example formats you have provided it look like you could distinguish GB and US. I will see if I can cook something up using `ParseExact`.

Comment: Even though there doesn't seem to be a general solution to my problem this solves the example in my question and I can work on from here implementing other needed languages. Thanks again Georg

Comment: Glad to help Pete :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support only a specific set of culture for dates, you can make use of the following code.

```
private static DateTime GetDateTime(string dateString){
        DateTime res = new DateTime();
        if(DateTime.TryParse(dateString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"),
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out res))
            return res;
        else if(DateTime.TryParse(dateString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out res))
            return res;
        else if(DateTime.TryParse(dateString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"),
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out res))
            return res;
        else if(DateTime.TryParse(dateString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"),
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out res))
            return res;
        //throw error or handle the not matcing case here
         Console.WriteLine("Not Matching "+dateString);           
        return res;
    }
```

Ideone:https://ideone.com/vTx614

Comment: I think this would break for an input like `12/11/1900` that was actually formatted from `en-US`, but would be interpreted as `en-GB`. We have to make some assumptions about the valid input formats, which need to be distinguishable.

Comment: Ya, That is correct. But in the question each date has a particular format that is unique for its culture. I was answering that particular case, need to figure out a better way.